# Geometric Proof that Gaussian Integers form PID

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-number-theory

In my reading on Algebraic Number Theory, I came across a description of a proof that the Gaussian Integers form a PID- you select a nonzero element $\alpha$ of minimal norm in the ideal, where the norm is the complex modulus squared, and form a lattice of its multiples in the complex plane (you can consider the square with vertices $0, \alpha, i\alpha,$ and $(1+i)\alpha$, and all other squares are translates of it). The ideal contains the vertices of the lattice, of course, so one need only show that the ideal contains no other points. The idea is that any other point in the plane would contradict the minimality of the norm of $\alpha$.

My idea was that since we're essentially working with the Euclidean norm, but squared, we can just consider four circles of radius $|\alpha|$ around each vertex of the aforementioned square and claim that any point $x$ in the square is contained in at least one of those four circles (not including the perimeter), so $x$ has distance less than $|\alpha|$ from one of the four vertices, call it $v$. Then we can just subtract multiples of $\alpha$ and $i$ from $x$ to get a point in the square where $0$ is the position of $v$, and so the distance between $0$ and $x$ is less than $|\alpha|$, meaning the norm of $x$ is less than the norm of $\alpha$.

I'm aware that my proof isn't rigorous, especially in the geometric part, but I'd just like to know if my idea is correct. (Also, I'm aware that one can prove the same thing by showing that the Gaussian integers form a Euclidean Domain, but I'm just interested in this particular proof.)

Comment: Roughly speaking, this is the "elementary" proof given by P. Samuel in his booklet "Théorie algébrique des nombres" (Hermann, Paris, I don't know if there is an English version), chapter 5, §5-6 .

Comment: Roughly speaking, this is the "elementary" proof given by P. Samuel in his booklet "Théorie algébrique des nombres" (Hermann, Paris; I don't know if there is an English translation), chapter 5 , §5.6 .